# Minimum value of an an expression

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the minimum value of $(\alpha-\beta)^2+(\sqrt{2-\alpha^2}-\frac{9}{\beta})^2$

where $ 0<\alpha<\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta>0$

My attempt:
In my view,this minimum value is the shortest distance between circle $x^2+y^2=2$ and rectangular hyberbola $xy=9$.But i dont know how to find.Any hints will help me.

Comment: you must differentiate this with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Sir,with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both at a time?

Comment: first $\alpha$ ($\beta$ const) and then $\beta$ ($\alpha$ const.)

Comment: i have found that the minimum is $8$ for $\alpha=1,\beta=3$

Comment: Sir cant this be solved geometrically?

Comment: i don't no at this time it takes more time for me, sorry

Comment: Sir i tried differentiating but not getting answer,getting complicated equations,can you give me steps,you followed.

Comment: geometricaly I think the answer would be 8. find the intersection of the line $y=x$ with the circle and the hyperbola. it will be $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$ the the square of the distance between these two points is 8

Comment: @sepideh, why did you find intersection with $y=x$ line only and not any other line.

Comment: because the minimum distance between a hyperbola and an ellipse having the same transverse axis is the distance between their vertices. and the vertex of a hyperbola or an ellipse is the point at which the transverse axis and hyperbola or ellipse intersect. here have a special case and the common transverse axis between hyperbola and circle is the line $y=x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view is right: if you draw the circle and the hyperbola it is apparent that the shortest distance $AB$ is measured along line $y=x$. Point $A$ lies on the circle, so $A(1,1)$, point $B$ is on the hyperbola: $B(3,3)$, so that $AB=2\sqrt2$ and $AB^2=8$.

Comment: why is shortest distance only along $y=x$ line,not any other line.

Comment: If you draw a sketch you'll see why. Or you want a formal explanation?

Comment: ,i got the concept,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the minimum distance between a hyperbola and an ellipse having the same transverse axis is the distance between their vertices. and the vertex of a hyperbola or an ellipse is the point at which the transverse axis and hyperbola or ellipse intersect. here have a special case and the common transverse axis between hyperbola and circle is the line $y=x$
find the intersection of the line y=x with the circle and the hyperbola. it will be (1,1) and (3,3) the the square of the distance between these two points is 8